# Connection String Error (error : 40)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, connection-string, sql-server-2012-express

I have installed SQL Server 2012 Express on a Windows Server 2008 Machine. The name of the machine is "THEMACHINE". While installation, I set SQL Server 2012 as "Default Instance".
Now I set my connection string like this :

```
<add name="BooksContext" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=THEMACHINE;Initial Catalog=newdb; User ID=sa; Password=123456"/>
```

But I get this exception :

> {"A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named
>   Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL
>   Server)"}

I checked that database is running. Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong?Thanks.

Comment: Can you ping and get a response from the DB server?

Comment: Try "Data Source=THEMACHINE\SQLEXPRESS;...

Comment: You should verify that `Named pipes` are enabled on the server (Configuration manager --> Client Protocols).

Comment: I did all of what you said, but still couldn't get it working. Thanks btw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reference: [**Creating and Configuring Universal Data Link (.udl) Files**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e38h511e(v=vs.71).aspx)

Do following to `Test connection` and `generate` connection string,

1) Create `query.udl` file in the desktop

2) Double click the file to open and do the following

[image]

3)Open the `Query.udl` in notepad, you will find the `connectionstring`.

Comment: Thank you. When I test the connection I get this error : **Test connection failed because of an error in initializing provider [DBNETLIB][ConnectionOpen(Connect()).] SQL Server does not exist or access denied.**

Answer (score 1):

Change Data Source=THEMACHINE to Data Source=THEMACHINE\SQLEXPRESS. Also check that the database service is running.