# DB connection not open

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, visual-studio-2012

i try this simple code with oledb connection but connection not open

```
    Imports System.Data.OleDb
Public Class WebForm2
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
    Protected Sub SubmitButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles SubmitButton.Click

        Dim connetionString As String
        Dim cnn As OleDbConnection
        connetionString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=((localdb)\v11.0);Initial Catalog=test;User Id=MyUsername; Password=MyPassword;Integrated Security=SSPI;"
        cnn = New OleDbConnection(connetionString)
        Try
           cnn.Open()
           MsgBox("Connection Open ! ")
           cnn.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception
           MsgBox("Can not open connection ! ")
        End Try
```

i also try this connection string

```
        connetionString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=test;Integrated Security=SSPI;"
```

same DB working well with sql client this connection string

```
    Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Public Class WebForm2

    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
    Dim globalp As String
    Dim globals As String
    Private strConn As String = "Data Source=(localdb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=test;Integrated Security=True"
```

extra code not mention for simplicity of question.
any thing extra required so please mention in comments.
also another problem is that some told me that this issue arise due to  SQL Server Authentication
i try to  change security authentication mode in visual studio built in sql server but i don't get properties popup menu or right below in vs corner section of properties, from Object Explorer,

New error occur in this code section  `Imports System.Data.OleDb

Public Class WebForm2

```
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
Dim globalp As String
Dim globals As String
'Dim strConn As String = "Provider=Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=((localdb)\v11.0);Initial Catalog=test;Integrated Security=SSPI;"
Dim strConn As String = "Provider=SQLNCLI11.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=Test;Data Source=(localdb)\v11.0;"

Dim conn As OleDbConnection
' Dim strConn As String = "Provider=SQLOLEDB; Data Source=(localdb)\v11.0; Initial Catalog=test; Integrated Security=SSPI"
'  Private strConn As String = " Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=(localdb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=test; User Id=MyUsername; Password=MyPassword"
' Private sqlCon As OleDbCommand
'Private strConn As OleDbCommand
'Provider=SQLOLEDB;


Protected Sub SubmitButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles SubmitButton.Click


    If Page.IsValid Then

        '  cnn = New OleDbConnection(strConn)
        '  cnn.Open()
        '  MsgBox("Connection Open ! ")
        '  cnn.Close()





        'sqlComm.CommandText = "sp1_userinformation"
        ' sqlComm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure



        ' sqlComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("UserName", name.Text)
        ' sqlComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("pass_word", fname.Text)
        ' sqlComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("CNIC", (cnic.Text))
        ' sqlComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("PartialAddress", (limitedtextarea.Text))
        ' sqlComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("Email", (email.Text))

        ' sqlCon.Open() 
        'lcit.Text = sname
        ' sqlComm.ExecuteNonQuery()
        ' Dim sname As String = name.Text
        Dim sfname As String = fname.Text
        Dim scnic As String = cnic.Text
        Dim slimit As String = limitedtextarea.Text
        Dim semail As String = email.Text
        Dim stel As Int64 = Int64.Parse(tel.Text)
        Dim stel1 As Int64 = 0 & stel
        Dim query As String = String.Empty
        Dim sdob As Date = Date.Parse(dob.Text)

        query &= "INSERT INTO Userinfo (UserName, pass_word, CNIC, "
        query &= "                     PartialAddress, Email, Telephone,DateOfBirth)  "
        query &= "VALUES (@colName,@colID, @colPhone, @colBranch,@colCourse,@coldblFee,@dobv)"
        ' query &= "                     PartialAddress, Email)  "
        ' query &= "VALUES (@colName,@colID, @colPhone, @colBranch,@colCourse)"
        ' Using (sqlCon)
        'sqlCon = New SqlConnection(strConn)
        ' Dim sqlComm As New SqlCommand()

        '  sqlComm.Connection = sqlCon
        Using conn As New OleDbConnection(strConn)
            Using comm As New OleDbCommand()
                With comm
                    .Connection = conn
                    .CommandType = CommandType.Text
                    .CommandText = query
                    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@colName", username.Text)
                    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@colID", sfname)
                    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@colPhone", scnic)
                    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@colBranch", slimit)
                    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@colCourse", semail)
                    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@coldblFee", stel1)
                    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@dobv", sdob)


                End With
                '  Try
                conn.Open()
                comm.ExecuteNonQuery()
                '  Catch(ex as SqlException)
                'MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString(), "Error Message")
                ' End Try
            End Using
        End Using

        ' End Using

    End If


End Sub`
```

Error is (Must declare the scalar variable "@colName".)
error location   comm.ExecuteNonQuery()

Comment: Refer this to test and autogenerate the SQLOLEDB connection string.....http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28344367/connection-string-error-error-40/28344559#28344559

Comment: Please also note that that exception object you caught, you know, `ex` in your code, probably has quite useful information that would *tell* you why the connection failed to open. But you're just *ignoring* that information.

Comment: Please don't edit your question into a *completely* different one. You've asked a question, you've got an answer, you've accepted it. If you have a new question, wait and ask a *new* question. If you're hitting a posting limit, that limit is there for a reason. You need to be a little bit *patient* and accept that there are *lots* of people who want to ask questions on here and there's no reason why your questions are more (or, for that matter less) important than anyone elses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with SQL Server Native Client instead:

```
Provider=SQLNCLI11.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=Test;Data Source=(localdb)\v11.0;
```

EDIT:

Your code would be:

```
    Dim connetionString As String
    Dim cnn As OleDbConnection
    connetionString = "Provider=SQLNCLI11.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=Test;Data Source=(localdb)\v11.0;"
    cnn = New OleDbConnection(connetionString)
    Try
       cnn.Open()
       MsgBox("Connection Open ! ")
       cnn.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
       MsgBox("Can not open connection ! ")
    End Try
```

Side Note: sql localdb does not work with SQL Server standard authentication, it only works with Windows integrated authentication.

Comment: boss it working well with sqlclient i have to do it with OleDbConnection

Comment: This connection string is for OleDbConnection, not for SqlClient. It uses SQL Server Native Client OLEDB Provider.

Comment: Thank you very much string gonna ok but new strange error occur i also finding ans from Google Must declare a scalar variable

Comment: Please, show the complete error. In what line of code does it throw? Do you have Test database on sql localdb?

Comment: complete code   Dim sname As String = name.Text
            Dim sfname As String = fname.Text
            Dim scnic As String = cnic.Text
                      Dim semail As String = email.Text
            Dim stel As Int64 = Int64.Parse(tel.Text)
            Dim stel1 As Int64 = 0 & stel
            Dim query As String = String.Empty
            Dim sdob As Date = Date.Parse(dob.Text) some code missing due to limited  comments validation on this site...... yes (database on sql localdb) ....In what line of code does it throw?here( comm.ExecuteNonQuery())

Comment: Please, open a new question

Comment: Not allowed by website wts ur email id or skype

Comment: I don't understand, you asked this question on S.O. What prevents you to ask a new question on StackOverflow?

Comment: dear jesus lopez i m new here at S.O so that with low reputaution so that their policy the S.O allowed me to oonly post one question in a whole day.? k i try if i am able to edit my question please help me dear friend.... or give me ur id?

Comment: please review the answer amendment

Comment: Why this answer is not an accepted answer anymore?. It solves your original first question.

Answer (score 0):

OleDbCommand's use positional parameters and the question mark ? as the parameter marker, as oposed to SqlCommand's that use named parameters. So the sql statement should be:

```
INSERT INTO Userinfo 
(
  UserName, pass_word, CNIC, PartialAddress, 
  Email, Telephone, DateOfBirth
)
VALUES (?,?, ?, ?,?,?,?)
```

To add parameters to OleDbCommand.Parameters collection you don't need to change anything, you can use the parameter name you want as long as all parameter names are different. But rememeber, you need to add the parameters in order, because parameters are positional.

Comment: what about   .Parameters.AddWithValue("@colName", username.Text)
                        .Parameters.AddWithValue("@colID", sfname)
                        .Parameters.AddWithValue("@colPhone", scnic)

Comment: That should work... But AddWithValue has some drawbacks, please see http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/

Comment: is that still Parameters ed query and save our db from injuction

Comment: Yes, it prevents sql injection